# Two columns one of the original value and other is the original unit, how do I convert the original values all into the same unit in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I important a complied data frame, then using dplyr selected the necessary columns.

```
  # select columns 
  dplyr::select(TraitID, OrigValueStr, OrigUnitStr)%>%
  # filter TraitID for 6 (root rooting depth)
  dplyr::filter(TraitID == 6) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(OrigValueStr))%>%
  #drops the TraitID column 
  dplyr::select(-TraitID)
```

But I am unsure on how to convert the OrigValuesStr values all into meters with a range of units from cm, inch and meters in the OrigUnitStr [two columns showing change in units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qko5.png). Initially though of a nested ifelse loop but I am still very new to R and have no real idea on how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your data (e.g. using `dput()`) rather than a screenshot?  Screenshots aren't searchable and the data can't be copied/pasted by other users to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `match` function is very useful in R. This is similar to what you would do in excel with `vlookup`.

```
units <- c("mm", "cm", "m", "km")
multipliers <- c(1/1000, 1/100, 1, 1000)
OrigValuesStr <- c(42, 69, 101)
OrigUnitsStr <- c("mm", "cm", "km")
result <- OrigValuesStr*multipliers[match(OrigUnitsStr, units)]
```

Here of course I created an example for your data because you did not provide a reproducible example, [please do so next time.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Basically `match(OrigUnitsStr, units)` returns `[1] 1 2 4` which are the indices of the **first** value in `units` that is equal to each of the values of `OrigUnitsStr`. So if you have a vector of `multipliers` you can apply the correct ones to the correct units, without a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to start by creating a reproducible problem with data

```
df<-data.frame(OrigValueStr=c("5","5","10","12","36","20"),
               OrigUnitStr=c("cm","cm","cm","inches","inches","inches"), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now, you have to do 2 things.

1. Mutate your values from strings to numbers(using the as.numeric function), and then
2. Mutate using a different formula depending on the unit (using case_when)

```
newdf<-df %>%
  mutate(OrigValue=OrigValueStr %>% as.numeric) %>%
  mutate(NewValue=case_when(
    OrigUnitStr=="cm" ~ OrigValue/100,
    OrigUnitStr=="inches" ~ OrigValue*2.54/100
  ))
```

Case_when keeps things more readable than a bunch of if_elses.